# Bucket Messages within 1 hour of first Message Timestamp and post 1 hour perform offset, per conversation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Chatlogs table with details of all the messages received by my application, a sample schema is as below.

[image]

My goal is to Bucket all the messages which where sent within 1 hour of receiving the first message over all the conversations,

For example the first message with **ChatId - 13-12-1987** was received at **30th May 2020 17:46** and from this TimeStamp I have to select all the items within the next 60 mins i.e., everything before **30th May 2020 18:46**. Now all the messages within this window is cassified as **Bucket 1** and the next window will begin again this time from the TimeStamp after 60 mins i.e., **30th May 2020 20:10**.

This whole operation has to happen over the **ConversationId** which means all the messages within that particular conversation and I have to calculate Buckets for all the conversations, some Conversations might only have 1 Bucket as all the Messages received would be with in 1 hour of the first message TimeStamp.

**Expected Result**

[image]

---

**My Take on this:**

I have built two solutions,

1. Using Cursors:I have built a logic to Partition Over Converstation ID and get minimum TimeStamp per conversation and I am building the Window and then updating accordingly.
2. Using Loops: This was an improvement over the Cursor, here I replaced the Cursor with WhileLoop and I was fetching individual rows using the Identity Column and then comparing.

In Both the approaches I was getting the desired output, but my Table has close to 500K recording and it takes around 5-7 hours to complete the entire operation. My DataBase is Azure SQL DB.

---

I am here looking for approaches to do this using Classic SQL and not using Cursors etc, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is just window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when incomingtimestamp < dateadd(hour, 1, min_its) then 1
             else 1 + row_number() over (partition by conversationid, (case when incomingtimestamp < dateadd(hour, 1, minits) then 1 else 2)
                                         order by incomingtimestamp
                                        )
        end) as bucket
from (select t.*, min(incomingtimestamp) over (partition by conversationid) as min_its
      from t
     ) t;
```

The idea is to assign everything that happens within an hour of the earliest timestamp a bucket of "1".  Then everything else gets a sequential timestamp.  The `case` is to define "everything else".  The `1 +` is to start the counting as `2`.